# Can you adjust default suggestion for Area and Iteration in Azure when creating new Work Item?

Tags: azure

When creating a new work item in Azure, you get suggestion for Area and Iteration.
The suggestion is always the same as your last saved work item.

However, I don't want Azure to suggest this.
The problem when you get these suggestions is that the work items ends up in wrong iteration paths and wrong area paths because the user forgets to adjust this.

I rather have no suggestion at all so that you remember to adjust before you can save the work item.
Is there any possibility to adjust this somewhere?

Googled but couldn't find any clue to change this.